# How can I write specific lines from a text area form to a text file? PHP

Tags: php, textarea, multiline

So I want to be able to paste this into the text area and I want it to write each particular `line/word` into the text file.

```
First Name Last Name
Home (123) 345-6789 
51 Street Name 
City, Pr ABC DEF
```

The text file should write in this format. `First Name Last Name!Home (123) 345-6789!51 Street Name!City! Pr !ABC DEF!`  (note the exclamation marks, spaces and coma). The program should be able to read all the words from line 1,2,3 regardless of how many words there are. Line 4 will be exactly in that format with 4 separate words. I need it to output in that particular format I listed above. This is what I'm confused about. If anyone has a solution for this I would greatly appreciate it. I've tried many things and I just can't seem to get my code to work. I'm new to this so if you could include as much as possible that would  be nice. Thank You.

Comment: Mind telling us more about "I've tried many things"?  Do you always want the last sub-string(after space) to be printed?

Comment: It seems like this should just require calling `explode()` on the input, looping over the lines, calling explode on each of them, then writing the last number in each of those arrays into the file.

Comment: Do you mean to write in file as `1111!1112!1113!1114 1121 1123` but be presented as is in the textarea?

Comment: I have edited my question to hopefully give you a greater insight on what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply making use of PHP's string functions.

```
<?php
$str='First Name Last Name
Home (123) 345-6789
51 Street Name
City, Pr ABC DEF';
$new_str="";
foreach(explode(PHP_EOL,$str) as $val)
{
    if(strpos($val,',')!==false)
    {
        $val=trim(str_replace(',','',$val)); //<--- For the space thing
        $val=explode(' ',$val);
        $new_str.=implode('!',$val)."!";
    }
    else
    {
        $new_str.=trim($val)."!"; //<--- Added here
    }
}
echo $new_str;
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
First Name Last Name!Home (123) 345-6789!51 Street Name!City!Pr!ABC!DEF!
```

Comment: thanks again for your help. One thing I noticed from your answer is there is an ! between ABC and DEF. The format I need is "First Name Last Name!Home (123) 345-6789!51 Street Name!City! Pr !ABC DEF!" so no ! between ABC and DEF. Also is it possible to have a space between ! and Pr before and after so like this "! Pr !". Thanks Again.

Comment: If you can give this a shot i would really appreciate it.  So the output should be First Name Last Name!Home (123) 345-6789!51 Street Name!City! Pr !ABC DEF!

Comment: Also its adding an extra space at the end after each line when I try to get the text from the text area form

Comment: Change like this `$val=trim(str_replace(',','',$val));`

Comment: Unfortunately the spacing issue still remains. Its outputs like this: First Name Last Name !Home (123) 345-6789 !51 Street Name !City!Pr!ABC!DEF! when I get the text from the text area.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that on `else` block.. Please see the code.